# Flex Drawing Edge using path, Show Preview

Tags: apache-flex, path, drag, preview, graphic

Hi am trying to connect two flex graphic objects using drag and drop (drag from source shape and drop on target, then a line is created that connect the two, using path object).

Is there any way that i can see a preview of the line while i am dragging between the shapes?

Answer (score 0):

Update a data object whenever the object moves, and bind the endpoints of the line to that data object.